# Why my code get wrong?

Tags: java

This question is from the Leetcode

Given a sorted linked list, delete all duplicates such that each element appear only once.
For example,
Given 1->1->2, return 1->2.
Given 1->1->2->3->3, return 1->2->3.

this is my java code ,and always get wrong answer.Please tell me the reason.

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode(int x) {
 *         val = x;
 *         next = null;
 *     }
 * }
 */
public class Solution {
    public ListNode deleteDuplicates(ListNode head) {
        if(head == null)return null;
        ListNode h1 = head;
        int size = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int count_num = 0;
        while(h1 != null){
            size++;
            h1 = h1.next;
        }
        ListNode[] list = new ListNode[size];
        list[0] = head;
        count_num++;
        head = head.next;
        while(count < size - 1){
                if(list[count_num - 1].val != head.val && head != null){
                    list[count_num] = head;
                    count_num++;
                }
            count++;
            head = head.next;
        }
        return list[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: Provide please ListNode class code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is doing nothing. You put the unique nodes in an array, but you don't change the linked list at all, and you return the same list you got as input.

Comment: As far, i dont even see where he is using LinkedList

Comment: @drgPP He's not using the standard LinkedList, but `ListNode` has a `next` property, which makes it a linked list.